# htop CPU time vs top CPU time

Tags: top, htop, cpu-usage

Both of the following pictures were taken with just seconds in between. `htop` shows 8:59.27 as consumed CPU time, while `top` shows it as 14:45:50 which seems legit. That's OS X 10.10 running on eight threads.

What the heck does `htop` list as CPU time?

[image: htop]

[image: top]